# Publish an Aperture smart album to Facebook

Tags: aperture, album

I can easily create a smart album with the 5-star rated images on a certain date. I would like to share those with a Facebook photo album but the share command is greyed out when I have a smart album selected. What are some other techniques I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the photos in the Album, see if that works for you.

Comment: If I could publish the Smart Album then I could republish it to FB when I add or change ratings. If I pick specific photos in the Album and I republish, then I will get duplicates in FB... However that might be my only choice.

Comment: You can select all the pics in the Smart Album (Command-a) and upload them. Then apply a coloured label to them. Then as new photos are added the one not uploaded will be obvious as they have no label - so easier to update your FB album